# SQL ORDER BY Idea

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.
Uploaders - id, name, icon, views
Videos - id, uploader, video, views

uploader column is used as reference to the uploader of the video. so, I am able to use sum() function to count how many views each user has in total from all of his videos. now i want to order these users by desc total views.

how do i do this? heres the code of what i have so far...

```
//Retrieve data from the database
$fkbar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM freaks");
while($fkrow = mysql_fetch_array($fkbar))

//Echo Theme Template on pages  
{   
    $frkid = $fkrow['id'];
    $viewq = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(views) AS vw FROM videos WHERE ref1='{$frkid}' OR ref2='{$frkid}' OR ref3='{$frkid}'");
    while($viewcnt = mysql_fetch_array($viewq))
    {       

        $viewcount = $viewcnt['vw'];

            echo "<div class='diva' id='{$viewcount}'>";
            echo "<div class='inner-diva'><a href='/mobile/freaks/?i={$fkrow['id']}'>";
            echo "<img id='{$fkrow['id']}' class='dvBarIco' src='/assets/ico/{$fkrow['icon']}' height='80px'></a></div>";
            echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, you're potentially wide open to SQL Injection.  You should be using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks. Im just a basic dev and seasonal designer, but after this phase the rest of the dev team should be securing my server side code for flaws and whatnot.

Comment: Heh... 'should be'.... Nobody ever has as much time as they think they do.  You owe it to both yourself (to increase your abilities), and your client (to protect their data) to look into this.  While doing parameterized queries isn't _hard_, looking up all instances and 'fixing' them would take time.  Make yourself more valuable to the company that hired you - find out what library they're using, and implement your queries using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `ORDER BY` clause using the aggregate:

```
ORDER BY SUM(views) DESC
```

From your comment, you can use a subquery in the first to do the ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM freaks f
ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(views) FROM videos WHERE ref1=f.id OR ref2=f.id OR ref3=f.id) DESC
```

You can also do this with a join, but the `OR` could make things complicated:

```
SELECT f.*, COALESCE(v.views, 0) total_views
FROM freaks f
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(views) views, id
    FROM (
        SELECT views, ref1 AS id
        FROM videos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT views, ref2 AS id
        FROM videos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT views, ref3 AS id
        FROM videos
    ) x
    GROUP BY id
) v ON f.id = v.id
ORDER BY total_views DESC
```

Comment: if u see the last group of echo statements, they're pulling info from the first query. but the first query isn't ordered by the view sums from the other table; basically i'd like to sort the first freaks.table with the sum(views) from the second videos.table of

Comment: thanks. the subquery worked flawlessly! i learn something new everytime i ask a question. i didnt even know about subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subselect to get the sum, which will combine both your queries and give you the option of ordering across both tables instead of in the second query each time.

```
$fkbar = mysql_query(
"SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(views) AS vw FROM videos WHERE videos.ref1=freaks.id OR videos.ref2=freaks.id OR videos.ref3=freaks.id) as total_views, 
* FROM freaks ORDER BY total_views DESC");
```